# Update table column with primary key after insert (in one statement)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, primary-key, sql-insert

Using an update statement, how can i directly set a column value to the primary key of an insert statement? I need this as one statement.

I know the following is wrong, but it helps get my idea through:

```
update AppNationalities
set CountrySelectionID = (
                            select [INSERTED.pkID] from
                            (
                                insert into CountrySelections
                                output INSERTED.pkID
                                values(CountryID, 'test', 0)
                            )
                        )
```

Comment: Which db you are using ? Please tag it along.

Comment: And why are you trying to achieve this at the same query ? First execute insert statement and then execute update maybe ?

Comment: im using SQL Server 2012

Comment: @ismetguzelgun im doing a widespread fix to many tables and would like to fix them all with simple SQL statements. No stored procedures or looping or anything... just a simple statement.

Comment: There is bunch of wrong doing in here. First i get that you want to achieve your goal in one go BUT there is no where clause in your statement. Let's think about it a little further though. You insert some values into CountrySelections table then what? How can AppNationalities table know which row it should be updating without a proper where clause ? Maybe AppNationalities does not even has a country you are looking for in the CountrySelections table right ?

Answer (score 0):

Put the values into a temporary table:

```
declare @ids table (pkID int);

insert into CountrySelections
    output INSERTED.pkID into @ids
    values (CountryID, 'test', 0);

update AppNationalities
    set CountrySelectionID = i.id
    from @ids i;
```

I don't think the `output` clause is allowed in the `FROM` clause of an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement.